# How can I view more counters in the Windows Server 2008 perfmon UI?

Tags: windows-server-2008, perfmon

On Windows Server 2008, if you set up perfmon counters, most of the UI is dedicated to the graph, and at the bottom of the screen you get a *tiny* scrollable area where you can only see one counter at a time.  Does anyone know how to fix it so that you can expand that area at the bottom?

Answer (score 0):

Just add more than 2 counters and it will dynamically expand that area.